# How to dynamically increase array size

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to read a file which contains the coordinate values for my code.

My question is, how do I make the array size large enough to contain future addition to the file?

Below is my code; when I set the array to size 905, my loop continues until the space is filled. Why is that?

`FILE.txt`:

```
S (60,70)(200,200)
S (30,40)(100,200)
S (10,20)(80,10)
S (60,400)(700,200)
S (160,70)(240,20)
S (160,70)(240,20)
S (160,70)(240,20)
```

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int a;
int b;
int c;
int d;
int data[905][4];
int main ( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    if ( argc != 2 ) /* argc should be 2 for correct execution */
    {
        /* We print argv[0] assuming it is the program name */
        printf( "usage: %s filename", argv[0] );
    }
    else 
    {
        // We assume argv[1] is a filename to open
        FILE *file = fopen( argv[1], "r" );

        /* fopen returns 0, the NULL pointer, on failure */
        if ( file == 0 )
        {
            printf( "Could not open file\n" );
        }
        else 
        {
            int j=0;int count=1
            for (j=0; j < count; j++) 
            {    
                fscanf(file, "S (%d,%d)(%d,%d)", &a, &b, &c, &d);

                printf("%d,%d,%d,%d\n",a, b, c, d);
                count++
            }             

            fclose( file );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please try to find a minimal example, it's not clear what you mean, want, or are are doing wrong... In general you will call `realloc()` or do something similar yourself..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use the `malloc` and `realloc` functions from `<stdlib.h>` for this.  The basic idea is to allocate a certain amount of space up front, and then enlarge the array when you discover that it is not big enough.

It will make life easier if you use an array of structures rather than an array of arrays:

```
struct segment { int x0, y0, x1, y1; };
```

and then you do something like this:

```
size_t nsegs = 0, segs_allocated = 10;
struct segment *segs = malloc(segs_allocated * sizeof(struct segment));
if (!segs) abort();

while (getline(&line, &linesz, stdin) >= 0)
{
    if (!parse_line(&segs[nsegs], line)) continue;
    nsegs++;
    if (nsegs == segs_allocated)
    {
        segs_allocated *= 2;
        segs = realloc(segs, segs_allocated * sizeof(struct segment));
        if (!segs) abort();
     }
}
```

Obligatory tangential comment: Forget you ever heard of `fscanf`.  It is far more trouble than it is worth.  Read entire lines with `getline` (if you don't have it, it's not hard to implement), extract individual number-strings from the line with a hand-coded parser, and convert them to machine integers with `strtol`, `strtoul`, or `strtod` as appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

With

```
int j=0;int count=1
for (j=0; j < count; j++) 
{

     fscanf(file, "S (%d,%d)(%d,%d)", &a, &b, &c, &d);

     printf("%d,%d,%d,%d\n",a, b, c, d);
     count++
}
```

you have a loop that keeps `count` one larger than `j` until `count++` overflows and gives you undefined behaviour. The compiler might well omit the loop control and make it an infinite loop since it may assume that no undefined behaviour occurs.

So the loop tries to read values from the file without end, or at least for a very long time. When the end of the file is reached, `fscanf` doesn't read any values, but since you don't check for its return value, that doesn't stop the loop. To avoid that, you could do something like

```
if (fscanf(file, "S (%d,%d)(%d,%d)", &a, &b, &c, &d) < 4) {
    break;
}
```

so that the loop ends when the end of the file is reached, or some input error occurs.

Regarding

> How do I make the array size large enough to contain future addition to the file?

You should then not use an array with statically defined dimensions, but allocate space using `malloc`

```
int (*data)[4] = malloc(num_rows * sizeof *data);
```

and when you need more,

```
int (*temp)[4] = realloc(data, new_num_rows * sizeof *data);
if (temp == NULL) {
    // reallocation failed, handle it or exit
} else {
    data = temp;
}
```

`realloc` a larger chunk of memory.

Comment: +1 for pointing out the "infinite" (until you overflow count) loop. I couldn't even begin to answer the question, myself, without addressing that glaring issue.